# Multi-lingual Action on Google failing

Tags: internationalization, multilingual, actions-on-google

In my `Action on Google` the language is getting reset to English again and again even when I have not called `i18n.setLocale`, I call it only once in the `Default Welcome Intent`.

Please let me know what might be wrong or how do I fix this.
TIA

Comment: You may need to call `i18n.setLocale` in every intent. If you do change that, see how that changes the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely due to promises, I wrote a blog about this, check out section #4 of [5 Tips when Localizing your Action (adding different languages)](https://medium.com/google-developers/5-tips-when-localizing-your-action-adding-different-languages-b4213cc9573f/#6737)

You can also see an example of how to correct for this in the [GDG Sample Action](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-gdg-nodejs)